# Read entire File to String Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a text file with path as `resources/templates/temp.txt`. I tried reading it with built in `Files.readAllBytes()` function found in java.nio but that results in an NullPointerException. My code looks as follows:

```
try {
        File file = new File(getClass().getResource("templates/temp.txt").getFile());
        String temp = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath())));
        System.out.println(temp);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The file actually does exist at this location because I am able to get an InputStream and use that in an InputStreamReader and BufferedReader to read the file line-by-line.

```
    InputStream input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)
    //path here is "templates/temp.txt"
```

I would like to read this file with a built in method rather than iterating over the entire thing.
Would appreciate it very much if someone can help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A `java.util.File` needs to be a physical resource on the file system. Something that is packaged in a jar/war/ear isn't a physical resource on the file system. So you can only read it with an `InputStream` and not a `File`.

Answer (score -1):

How does your code even compile? You have static reference in non-static env:

```
... new File(getClass().getResource ...
```

try to get the bytearray before transforming into string:

```
try {
    byte[] tmpba = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("templates/temp.txt"));
    String s = new String(tmpba);
    
    System.out.println(s);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It compiles just fine. Syntactically the code snippets posted are correct . It does not throw any compilation error. As far I can see, there has been no static reference at all. The line mentioned used getResource() method

Comment: This results in java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Comment: you never mentioned you were using a packaged file. So it makes perfect sense. Thnx to @M. Deinum.